# eureka client not registering with eureka server in spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I used spring boot 3.0.1 with spring cloud 2022.0.0 to implement eureka server and eureka client. Both running successfully but my eureka cient not registered with eureka server. I got error like :

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Root name ('timestamp') does not match expected ('instance') for type `com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo`
```

Here below my eureka server pom.xml dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version> 
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.eazybytes</groupId>
<artifactId>eurekaserver</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging> 
<name>eurekaserver</name>
<description>Service discovery for Bank microservices</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version> 
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <name>eazybytes/${project.artifactId}</name>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here below my eureka application.properties code

```
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=eurekaserver
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Here below my eureka main class

```
package com.eazybytes.eurekaserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaserverApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaserverApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here below my client pom.xml dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.eaztbytes</groupId>
<artifactId>accounts</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>accounts</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version> 
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>
    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                 <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Here below my eureka client application.properties code

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8071

spring.application.name=accounts 
spring.profiles.active=prod
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8072

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
info.app.name=Accounts-Microservice
info.app.description=Eazy-Bank-Accounts-Application
info.app.version=1.0.0
management.info.env.enabled = true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
```

Lastly my eureka main class

```
package com.eaztbytes.accounts;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.eaztbytes.accounts")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RefreshScope
@EntityScan("com.eaztbytes.accounts.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.eaztbytes.accounts.repository")
public class AccountsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I spent maybe 3 days without success. I really need help. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I made a stupid mistake. In my eureka client application properties file I added a space after application name value, especially that parameter spring.application.name. So instead of that "spring.application.name=accounts" I wrote "spring.application.name=accounts ".
When I looked my eureka client log and saw a message like:

```
DiscoveryClient_ACCOUNTS/DESKTOP-PB1AV09.mshome.net:accounts :8071: registering service...
```

I paid attention and I noticed that there is a space between application name and port. So in my eureka client application properties file, when I removed the space from my application name value, now I got in my eureka log:

```
DiscoveryClient_ACCOUNTS/DESKTOP-PB1AV09.mshome.net:accounts:8071: registering service...
```

It's work fine after that. Blame on me, and sorry for that.